# TextView not initially loading but subsequently loads

Tags: uitextview, nstimer

I am making an app where I pass text entered by a user in a textview to a second view controller and then place it back in a textview where some animations are done.

My problem is that the initial time the second view controller loads it takes a long time and the textview doesn't show up at all. After the first time the textview loads up perfectly every time. I also have a timer set to initialize with the new view controller but it fires instantly instead of waiting.

The weird part is that my animations all wait until the view is loaded as they are supposed to. It's just the timer and the textview that are the problems but only the first time. If I repeat the process the timer, textview and animations all fire perfectly together and when they are supposed to and the view controller loads instantly, unlike the first time which seems to take forever.

Does anyone have any ideas that might help? Why would they all work perfectly after the first time but not the first?

Thanks guys and gals! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone...

Apparently it had something to do with the way I was layering my animations. For some reason they would not work until I put the textview animation block inside of my imageview animation block. Until I did this the textview block simply would not fire the first time. I had to put my two timers into the completion handler of the imageview block and now it all works perfectly except I still have some lag the first time it loads. But I'm not as concerned about that as I was with the animations and timers. I find it weird that after the initial load it would work but it makes sense since I now know it was not firing in the right order.

If anyone would like more info on this let me know. I will post code if anyone is interested